# Instagram api your followers date when they followed you

Tags: php, api, instagram, instagram-api

Im using the instagram api to get a list of my followers BUT i get the following..

```
(
    [username] => someone
    [profile_picture] => somephoto.jpg
    [id] => 00101010101
    [full_name] => Awesome Name
)
```

But its missing the time? How can i find out what time someone followed me? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find such information in the API - https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/ - so it isn't delivered I'm afraid.

Comment: Thats a shame, would out been useful to have. Thanks anyway